# Why would the loss increase on a single fixed input?

Tags: neural-networks, objective-functions

I'm training a neural network on some input data. I know that loss increasing may be related to:

- overfitting, if the loss increases on test data (while still decreases on training data)
- oscillations near the optimal point, if the learning rate is too big

However, I find that while for some input data the net makes good predictions, for other data the loss continues to increase, even if I only train on *one data point* and if the learning rate is fairly low. To me, it's quite strange that performing the training on only one point the loss continues to increase and not decreases; in fact, the only reason I can find for this is a big learning rate.

Can you think about some other reason?

Comment: by loss, do you mean validation/training error? or do you mean the actual loss function? its also hard to evaluate this without knowing the architecture involved....